# redirecting to a page url in php

Tags: php

I have folowing code in which i am using some conditions on page to be open or redirected to any other url but php method for calling a url is not working here please any one help me how to get out of this issue
here is my php code

```
<?php

$good_domains = array("http://172.17.0.221:84/cp.aspx","http://172.17.0.221:84/cp.aspx");
if(!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$good_domains)){
echo "<script>alert(\"NO\");</script>";
Redirect('http://www.google.com.pk');
}
else{
echo "<script>alert(\"YES\");</script>";
//echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
//Redirect('http://www.shakarganj.com.pk');

$URL="http://www.google.com"; 

header ("Location: $URL");
}

?>
```

When i run the page the folowing error is generated.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampplite\htdocs\a\sfpl\MT.php:9) in C:\xampplite\htdocs\a\sfpl\MT.php on line 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your index file add this:

```
ob_start();
```

This will remove this warning if i'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do a header based redirect if you have already sent information to the browser, which your call to `echo` will do.  You must remove the calls to `echo`, and also make sure that there is no whitespace in front of your first `</php` tag.

Comment: Its Ok But I have to use the echo also and after the message in echo i want to redirect how this may possible ?

Comment: You want to display the message to the user, and then redirect?  You will have to use a client side solution for the redirect in that case, either JavaScript or a meta tag. @balkon_smoke's answer provides a JS solution.

Comment: @user1220667 whats the point of echo-ing something then redirecting ????? do it client side if you want to show a message `location.href = <url>` in JavaScript

Comment: if he wants to do it server side he can make use of `ob_Start()` and `ob_end_flush()` functions. http://php.net/ob_start and http://php.net/ob_end_flush  The way this answer is written isn't exactly telling him that there is a solution to his problem, just telling him more information on what is causing the warning message.

Answer (score 3):

Direct from the `header()` [help page here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) :

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(),
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called.

You `echo` a script tag in both sides of the `if` statment - you need to remove them on your redirect side

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answers above — if you use JS to display **YES/NO** alert, why did you use PHP for redirecting?

You can redirect user in JS:

```
alert("NO"); document.location.replace("http://google.co.uk");
// otherwise
alert("YES"); document.location.replace("http://google.com");
```

And if you want to have delay before user will be redirected, you can use `setTimeout` function:

```
alert("NO");
// wait 5 seconds before redirect
setTimeout(5000, function()
{
    document.location.replace("http://google.co.uk");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already done an `echo` statement, PHP cannot send anymore headers to the output.

You have to make sure that any `header()` calls are performed before any other output to your page.

Answer (score 2):

that is a standard error; the header sends http headers and 
at the moment the output is started, the headers are already sent

in this case you can avoid this problem by using output buffering (check http://php.net/ob_start); you need the option to be enabled on your server and to check your buffer size

Answer (score 0):

use

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0; URL=your_url">';
```